# How to use Google Analytics in Android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-analytics

In my application i want to use **Google analytics** to show users **log**!
I write below codes, but after running application it does **not show** me any events on **google analytics dashboard**!
I have **`application class`** and initialize **google analytics** code into this class and use this class in `fragments` or `activities` !
After set **redPoint** for **debugging**, show me null **Tracker** and **Analytics**!
**My App class :**

```
class App : Application() {
    private var analytics: GoogleAnalytics? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //Google Analytics
        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this)
        //Fabric initialize kits
        val fabric = Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(Crashlytics())
            .debuggable(true)
            .build()
        Fabric.with(fabric)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun getDefaultTracker(): Tracker? {
        var tracker: Tracker? = null
        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context) // here pass your activity instance
        analytics?.let {
            tracker = it.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
        }
        return tracker
    }

    fun googleTracker(category: String, action: String, label: String) {
        val tracker: Tracker? = getDefaultTracker()
        tracker?.send(
            HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory(category)
                .setAction(action)
                .setLabel(label)
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

**Fragment codes :**

```
App().googleTracker(ANALYTICS_SIGNUP_CATEGORY, ANALYTICS_SIGNUP_SIGNIN_ACTION, "")
```

Debugging images : 
[image]

[image]

Comment: please use [FirebaseAnalytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start).

Comment: @NiravBhavsar, My PO says we should use Google Analytics ! can you help me?

Comment: please check this link : https://proandroiddev.com/integrate-app-analytics-into-your-android-kotlin-app-with-aws-mobile-29d3c4c5acb0

Comment: @unzila, in your link use AWS Mobile ! i want use Google Analytics

Comment: @KokoBand, i dont know very much about google analytics, as its sdk might be moved to version3 and might be other change, so please check this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration) in detail.

Comment: maybe your tracking id is wrong , recheck this id

Comment: @unzila, i check it. it's not wrong! my tracking id is true!

Comment: @unzila, and also i use firebase analytics! not show any event too in firebase event panel

Comment: basically when you create tracker id and them embed it in your project then firebase takes time to show analytics on your firebase account, wait for half an hour . all analytics will display soon

Comment: @unzila, yes firebase show me events! but not show me my custom event!

Comment: @unzila, can you see my above images? why show me null ?!!! i think my issue is null

Comment: yes because you are not initializing your analytics variable inside tracker function. check in your image analytics is null too,

Comment: @unzila, how can i fix it? can you edit my codes?

Comment: @unzila, in other side i used firebase analytics. in this way not show me null error! and not show event in dashboard! why not show me event???

Comment: firebase analytics code is working fine?

Comment: @unzila, firebase analytics not show me any error (null or more) , but not show me any event in dashboard!!!

Comment: firebase takes time to display data on dashboard.

Comment: @unzila,I'm waiting for more than an hour and not giving anything

Comment: @unzila, hey your answer is for `analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context)` help to me. thanks thank you for help me! please post your answer and accept it. perhaps help to another developers.

Comment: u welcome .............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should initialize google analytics in this function:

```
 @Synchronized
fun getDefaultTracker(): Tracker? {
    var tracker: Tracker? = null
    analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context) // here pass your activity instance
    analytics?.let {
        tracker = it.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
    }
    return tracker
}
```

Comment: This code generates a new instance of Tracker along with hitting the disk to get the xml configuration every time it is called.  Potentially very inefficient.  The idea is to only get a newTracker if the tracker property of your Application is null.

Comment: you can call this function in init or your application class, to generate only one instance

Answer (score 1):

Yes Google has newer analytics tools that they would prefer we use but some of us have business reasons to continue with the old v4 analytics.

Starting with [their original suggested implementation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4), which was written in java, here is a Kotlin version.

```
class MyApplication: Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var googleAnalytics: GoogleAnalytics
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this)
    }
}
```

Next Google suggests the Application instance generate and provide a shared instance of the Tracker for use by your various Activities and Fragments.  But in Kotlin, I found it much cleaner to set up a separate companion object...

```
object Analytics {
    var tracker: Tracker

    init {
        @Synchronized
        tracker = MainApplication.googleAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
    }
}
```

Firing screen views and events throughout your app can be done as follows:

```
    Analytics.tracker.setScreenName("Screen Name")
Analytics.tracker.send(HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build())

    Analytics.tracker.send(
        HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("foo")
            .setAction("bar)
            .setLabel("baz")
            .build()
    )
```